# Blender VSE - speed control and cross effect at the same time

Tags: video-sequence-editor, effects

I try to use cross effect between two stripes and set speed control effect to one of these stripes , only one of these effects works (the one which is on the top). 
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to put the cross on the speed control strip, not the original strip. You see only the cross at the moment because it is the top most.

Here is the step by step process:

1. Add the speed strip  (in your case to the `rejs_anima...` image strip)
2. Select the newly added **speed strip** (not the original image strip) and the second video strip (`MVI_...` in your case) then
3. Add the cross strip